# Is there a geometric picture between Chern class and Chern character?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, fiber-bundles, characteristic-classes

I'm new to the characteristics classes. When I learn the definition of Chern class and Chern character, the total Chern class is defined as:
$$c(\mathcal F)=\det(I+\frac{i \mathcal F}{2\pi}),$$
where $\mathcal F$ is the curvature matrix or field strength, $i=\sqrt{-1}$. The total Chern character is defined as:
$$\operatorname{ch}(\mathcal F)=\operatorname{tr}(\exp(\frac{i \mathcal F}{2\pi})).$$
You see there is a $\det$ and a trace, which remind me of the famous identity in Lie group: $\det(\exp(A))=\exp(\operatorname{tr}(A))$, which leads to the fact that there is a $\det(A)=1$ in definition of $\mathrm{SL}$, so there is a trace=0 in $\mathrm{sl}$.

So my question is, is there also a similar geometric picture between Chern class and Chern character? similar to the relationship between a Lie group and its Lie algebra? I see only their algebraic equivalence in the textbooks I can find.
Thank you.

Comment: F is curavature or field strength. I've modified it in thet text.

Comment: Please do *not* use $*$ for multiplication. Mathematics is not a computer program; moreover, in geometry $*$ has an important meeting (the Hodge star operator on differential forms).

Comment: You are right. I deleted that star.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think that this is the correct 'compatibility', but both invariants certainly follow a similar geometric construction, which lives in the realm of supergeometry. The total Chern class can be build as $\det\circ \exp_G$ where $\exp_G:\mathfrak{g}\to G$ is the exponential map of a (infinite dimensional super) Lie-group. The Chern character might be interpreted as the (super) trace of a (super) parallel transport. As far as I know the last statement is due to [Fei Han](https://arxiv.org/abs/0711.3862).

**The following is a naive and probably incorrect description of these ideas and is avoiding the language of supermanifolds.**

Let's setup notation first: Let $\pi:E \to M$ be a (smooth) complex vector bundle over a manifold with given connection $\nabla$. From this one can build a *superconnection* (a differential operator): $$d^\nabla:\Omega(M,E) \to \Omega(M,E).$$ Note that $\Omega(M,E)$ is a supermodule over the superalgebra $\Omega(M)$ and $d^\nabla$ is an odd operator. Now $(d^\nabla)^2 = \frac{1}{2}[d^\nabla,d^\nabla]$ is $\Omega(M)$-linear (a differential operator of order $0$) and is given by multiplication with the curvature $\mathcal{F} \in \Omega^2(M,\mathrm{End}(E))$. Moreover one has the Bianchi identity: $(d^\nabla)^3 = 0$.

Now let $G$ be the group of $\Omega(M)$-linear automorphisms of $\Omega(M,E)$.
Set $A := \mathcal{F}/(2\pi i) $ and
define two paths in $G$:
\begin{align*}\alpha(t) &:= 1 + t  A\\
\beta(t) &:= \exp(tA)\end{align*}
$\alpha$ is the essentially the one parameter subgroup of $G$ which is tangent to $A$ at the identity and therefore we might set $\exp_G(A) = \alpha(1) = 1+\mathcal{F}/(2\pi i)$.  Note that there is a determinant $\det:G \to \Omega(M)^\times$  and we have $c(E,\nabla)=\det(\exp_G(A))$.

$\beta$ essentially satisfies a differential equation belonging to a parallel transport (not clear here what the loop is). That is we have for $v \in \Omega(M,E)$ that
$ d^\nabla \exp(tA)v = td^\nabla A \cdot\exp(tA)v = 0$
by the Bianchi identity $d^\nabla A = 0$.
Here the parallel transport is a $\Omega(M)$-linear automorphism $P: \Omega(M,E) \to \Omega(M,E)$ and the Chern character is given by its trace.

Remarks:

1. You do have $\det(\exp_G(A)) = \exp_{\Omega(M)^\times}(\mathrm{tr}_\mathfrak{g}(A))$ but this does not connect to the Chern character.
2. I am using a different sign convention for the total Chern class ($i^{-1} = -i$). I strongly believe one should not seperate $2\pi$ from $i$ here.